# Objective c enum value in form of string literal within single qoutes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums

Found enum declaration in `AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h`

```
enum
{
    kAudioSessionNoError                                =  0,
    kAudioSessionNotInitialized                         = '!ini',
    kAudioSessionAlreadyInitialized                     = 'init',
    kAudioSessionInitializationError                    = 'ini?',
    kAudioSessionUnsupportedPropertyError               = 'pty?',
    kAudioSessionBadPropertySizeError                   = '!siz',
    kAudioSessionNotActiveError                         = '!act',
    kAudioServicesNoHardwareError                       = 'nohw',
    kAudioSessionNoCategorySet                          = '?cat',
    kAudioSessionIncompatibleCategory                   = '!cat',
    kAudioSessionUnspecifiedError                       = 'what'
};
```

I don't really understand what this declaration actually is. Google doesn't provide any information. Any help please?

Comment: Oh, some kind of 4-char not null-terminated arrays in place where 4-byte Integer should be? Pretty weird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are called «four char codes»:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC

They are converted to integers (32 bits, as they are 4 chars), but improved the readability comapred to numeric values.
Apple uses this from a long time, mainly for OSStatus codes.